# How to select rows from data.frame with 3 "dynamic" conditions from other table?

Tags: r, dplyr

So here is my table named `qb`:

```
GameID Qtr      Drive   Down  Passer

1      1        1       1     A
1      1        2       1     A
1      1        2       2     A
1      1        2       3     A
```

and here is second table named `sacks` which I want to be used for filtering

```
gameId Qtr      Drive   Down  Sack

1      1        2       2     yes
1      1        2       3     yes
```

I try to filter rows of QB table where gameID, Drive and Down are same as in sacks table.

```
GameID Qtr      Drive   Down  Passer

1      1        2       2     A
1      1        2       3     A
```

I tried `dplyr` and `qb %>% filter(Drive == sacks$Drive & Down==sacks$Down & gameID==sacks$gameID)` but it doesn't work. I could use merge but looking for some "filter solution" (my example is simplier then what I'm trying to handle). Also I'm receiving weird warning

> ```
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 2: In c(NA, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,  :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

EDIT: I think I over-complicated my question. I will try once again. I have table qb like in example and second table where I have 2 columns: gameID and Drive. As my final result I want to see all rows where GameID = gameID and Drive=Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::semi_join` is built for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)

semi_join(qb, sacks %>% rename(GameID = gameId))
##   GameID Qtr Drive Down Passer
## 1      1   1     2    2      A
## 2      1   1     2    3      A
```

You could use the `by` parameter instead of `rename`, but that's more typing in this case.

Comment: I think I over-complicated my question. I will try once again. I have table qb like in example and second table where I have 2 columns: gameID and Drive. As my final result I want to see all rows where GameID  = gameID and Drive=Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic subsetting:

```
qb[qb$GameID == sacks$gameId &
       qb$Drive == sacks$Drive &
       qb$Down == sacks$Down,]
#  GameID Qtr Drive Down Passer
#3      1   1     2    2      A
#4      1   1     2    3      A
```